# Инспекция кода: пример "одностраничника"

Tags: angularjs, инспекция-кода

Под спойлером часть функционала проекта для складского учета, если быть более точным то страница отображающая текущие остатки с возможностью фильтрации по конкретным номенклатурам.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.select']);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.model = {
    trackedAssets: []
  };

  dataService.getAssets()
    .then(assets => {
      console.log(assets);
      $scope.assets = assets;
    })
    .then(() => {
      return dataService.getResidues();
    })
    .then(residues => {
      console.log(residues);
      $scope.residues = residues;
    });


});

app.filter('trackedAssetsFilter', function() {
  return function(items, trackedAssets) {
    if (trackedAssets.length == 0)
      return items;
    return items.filter(item => {
      return trackedAssets.some(asset => {
        return asset.Number == item.AssetNumber || asset.OrderCode == item.AssetOrderCode;
      });
    });
  }
})


app.factory('dataService', function($timeout) {
  let assets = [{
      'Number': 911304165,
      OrderCode: '36208 Подшипники шариковые радиально-упорные ГОСТ 831-75'
    },
    {
      'Number': 863004067,
      OrderCode: 'Щетка обдирочная для заточного станка АТАКА круглая 181'
    },
    {
      'Number': 863004068,
      OrderCode: 'Щетка обдирочная для заточного станка АТАКА круглая 031'
    },
    {
      'Number': 863004069,
      OrderCode: 'Щетка обдирочная для дрели АТАКА круглая 083'
    }
  ];
  let residues = [{
      'AssetNumber': 911304165,
      AssetOrderCode: '36208 Подшипники шариковые радиально-упорные ГОСТ 831-75',
      Quantity: 4,
      Price: 762.71
    },
    {
      'AssetNumber': 863004067,
      AssetOrderCode: 'Щетка обдирочная для заточного станка АТАКА круглая 181',
      Quantity: 1,
      Price: 529
    },
    {
      'AssetNumber': 863004068,
      AssetOrderCode: 'Щетка обдирочная для заточного станка АТАКА круглая 031',
      Quantity: 1,
      Price: 280
    },
    {
      'AssetNumber': 863004069,
      AssetOrderCode: 'Щетка обдирочная для дрели АТАКА круглая 083',
      Quantity: 1,
      Price: 109
    }
  ];
  return {
    getAssets: function() {
      return $timeout(function() {
        return assets;
      }, 500);
    },
    getResidues: function() {
      return $timeout(function() {
        return residues;
      }, 500);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-route.js"></script>
  <link data-require="ui-select@*" data-semver="0.19.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.19.4/select.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="ui-select@*" data-semver="0.19.4" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.19.4/select.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ui-select multiple ng-model="model.trackedAssets">
          <ui-select-match>
            <span>{{$item.Number}} {{$item.OrderCode}}</span>
          </ui-select-match>
          <ui-select-choices repeat="asset in (assets|filter:$select.search)">
            <span ng-bind="asset.OrderCode"></span>
            <p class="text-muted" ng-bind="asset.Number"></p>
          </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Номенклатурный номер</th>
        <th>Наименование</th>
        <th>Кол-во</th>
        <th>Стоимость</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="residue in residues|trackedAssetsFilter:model.trackedAssets">
        <td ng-bind="residue.AssetNumber"></td>
        <td ng-bind="residue.AssetOrderCode"></td>
        <td ng-bind="residue.Quantity|number:3"></td>
        <td ng-bind="residue.Price|number:2"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Что меня смущает:

необходимость писать так: `$scope.model = {trackedAssets:[]};` вместо: `$scope.trackedAssets = []`;

правильность получения данных необходимых для представления, да я могу предварительно их получить в модуле `ngRoute` но не знаю для этого ли предназначен метод `resolve` и как принято делать.

Так же хотелось бы оценки реализации фильтра